# Element not recognized

Tags: coded-ui-tests

Working on Coded UI testing and for scripts developed using Record Capture and playback feature (ctrl +I).

The problem is when the page has sub-menus (e.g. I need to hover over menu link then click sub-menu). When I record and capture element using Ctrl+I and executed a script it recognizes, but when I ran the script for the second time the element gets changed and it's not recognized.

I have tried simple x path utility posted [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2011/12/28/sample-xpath-utility-for-coded-ui-test.aspx) but coudn't able to use this feature. What would be the problem for always element id's getting changed. How to resolve it ?

Comment: Could you post some of your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it isn't a nested object?

See http://executeautomation.com/blog/how-to-identify-all-the-child-elements-within-a-page-in-coded-ui-test-cuit/

You could also try EnsureClickable()

Answer (score 0):

There could few reasons behind not recognizing an element:

1. List item Element is not visible when you are trying to click on it.
2. If Type of Parent Element is e.g. winclient then it’s difficult in coded UI to identify its child elements.

There could various solutions, you can try:

1. First Click on Menu Item and then click on Sub Menu Item, if you are directly clicking on sub menu item in your recorded script, this will make sub menu element visible.
2. Also you can check the visibility from Coded UI Test Builder-> Add Assertion button then going to UI Control Map, then select the element in tree and click on Refresh. It will show if element is visible or not.
3. If Ids are changing, then you can various other properties like Name, ClassName, InnerText, ControlType, TagInstance, ControlName etc. whichever is supported by Element.